# change background image of imageview on onclick

Tags: android

I have imageview and i whant when user click this imageview the background of this changed this is my code

```
 btnImage =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_button); 
 btnImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

       public void onClick(View arg0) {


       Intent i=new Intent(fierst.this,second.class);
       startActivity(i);

       }
   });
```

but i dont know how in onclick change this background image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm agree with @sajidkhan answer but @zahra you are doing mistake to set the selector as background wrong.
 here i will explain @sajidkhan's answer as i know he might be expected here an image.png etc not a selector.xml

```
 buttonONE.setBackground(R.drawable.round_button_focus);
```

**round_button_focus** means **round_button_focus.png** etc,

in `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` set one background and when you release the button set another background eg. `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`
follow @sajidkhan suggestion his answer might deserve as accepted if you think this helped you.

Comment: i copy my picture png in drawable file but i have errore in setbackground and my errore say i should change the setbackground to other method :(

Comment: change it to setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image);
hope this help you :) accept answer if you solved problem,

Answer (score 3):

Why you do not use Selctor for `ImageView` when clicked.

res/drawable/selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/your_iamge_pressed"         android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/your_iamge_pressed"
  android:state_focused="true"
  android:state_enabled="true"
  android:state_window_focused="true"  />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/your_iamge_normal" />
```

here in you ImageView set the selector as background : `android:background="@drawable/selector.xml"`

```
<ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/selector.xml" />
```

**OR USE TouchListener To implement such idea**
when you touch(Action Down) set one image as background and when you release (Action Up) set another Image as background.

here is the code

```
buttonONE.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
   {
   if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

     buttonONE.setBackground(R.drawable.round_button_focus);


   } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

     buttonONE.setBackground(R.drawable.round_button_unfocused);
      //  *******start Intent here********
   }
  }
};
```

Comment: edited answer :) if you want to replace images each other on clicked.

Comment: i have many button and each one have diffrent image how many selector xml should write? @Sajidkhan

Comment: each have different bg images? can you post you UI which you want to implement, i mean screen shot?

Comment: i have several image and every one have diffrent background i whant when user click on image this background changed @Sajidkhan

Comment: can you post a screen shot? so i will suggest you a solution :)

Comment: Answer updated. have a look at the updated suggestion if solved accept answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
  btnImage =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_button); 
         btnImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

               public void onClick(View arg0) {

               btnImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
             //put your image in drawable folder and change ic_luncher by your image.
               Intent i=new Intent(fierst.this,second.class);
               startActivity(i);


               }
           });
```

**Intent i=new Intent(fierst.this,second.class);**

**startActivity(i);**

by executing these two line it will move to second activity so you can't able to see the result for image changed or not. To see the proper output for image change make these lines as comment

*Hope this will helpful .thanks*

Comment: i whant see the result of changed backgroud and go to second activity how can do this

Comment: remove the intent code or you can use it in many other ways like onClick listener to a button or any other event except this image onClick event..ok@zahra